# Sublime Text add new lines between paragraphs

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there a way to add lines (separate text) between paragraphs in ST?
For example, I have a text in form like:

*Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.*

and I would like to separate it on the three paragraphs like this:

*Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.*

*Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.*

*Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.*

Comment: Pressing Enter twice should do just fine.

Comment: It's not just twice if you after every paragraph have to press enter.

Comment: Right. So the enhanced answer would be "twice per *new paragraph*". For your desired *three*  paragraphs, that would be 2*2=4. Generalizing: "press Enter *n* times should do just fine, with `n=2*(numDesiredParagraphs-1)`. I'm still in the dark if this is a very good question and I am overlooking some caveat (i.e., "does pressing Enter in ST3 actually insert a Hard Return?") or if you are somehow complicating simple things.

Comment: Just like in any text editor or word processor, if you're done with a paragraph, hit `Enter` twice to insert a blank line and start a new paragraph. Is that all that you're asking?

Comment: I have a form of the text with more recurring paragraph as I stated in the example. I thought there is a funcionality in ST in which I can found last word or character and add a new lines after one Enter hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime text's find and multiple-selection features are your friends here.  In your example, each paragraph ends with `Lorem Ipsum.`.

1. Bring up the Find pane (from the `Find` menu -> `Find...` or press Ctrl+F on the keyboard).
2. Type `Lorem Ipsum.`. (or, if regex mode is turned-on, type `Lorem Ipsum\.`.)
3. Press the `Find All` button.  This will select all instances of `Lorem Ipsum.`.
4. Press the right arrow key on your keyboard.  This will move the cursors to the end of the selections, which is where you want your newlines to be.
5. Press the enter key on your keyboard twice.  You now have a blank line separating the paragraphs. :)